# Issue connecting a Node.js app to a MongoDB using docker-compose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

Hy, I am pretty new to docker and I am having some issue understanding how containers interact with each other in the docker world created using a docker compose

I have a docker-compose.yaml file that contain 2 services:

1. A MongoDB service which is suppose to create a MongoDB database
2. A Node.js app service that is trying to connect to that MongoDB database

When i try to run the docker-compose up command I get an error letting me know there was a issue connecting to my MongoDB instance.

```
info: Listening on port 3000...
error: uncaughtException: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError'
```

This is my docker-compose.yaml file

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb_container
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data_container:/data/db

  my_app: 
    container_name: my_app_container
    image: my_app:1.0
    ports: 
      - 3000:3000
```

Can anyone help me out with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your are not providing network informations, so I suppose you are using default network.
In your app container, **"localhost" is your container localhost** (not the localhost of your host machine).

Instead of using "localhost", use the container name "mongodb_container" in your app to connect to your db on port "27017" (to be clear : 27017 is the port exposed by your mongo container, not 27017 opened on the host localhost).

Check : https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

> By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each
> container for a service joins the default network and is both
> reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by
> them at a hostname identical to the container name.

Comment: Thank you for the information I was able to connect to the MongoDb data base. But now when i try to send a curl command from within the docker containers - curl http://mongodb_container:3000/api/user - to the node app i get a connection refused - curl: (7) Failed to connect to mongodb_container port 3000: Connection refused

Comment: I don't understand, you are mixing you api port with mongodb container name.
If you want to reach your API, you can try to curl on : my_app_container:3000/api/user

Comment: Thank you very much. This was indeed my mistake. It all works perfect now.

Comment: Nice ! You can accept my answer to close your question.